# Axios cors header not appearing on request

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios, xmlhttprequest

I have an axios request to the backend. And our backend said that he already configure the cors for the front end. But when I send my axios request. It only gets me this headers even if I put an header in my post request.

[image]

Here is my axios

```
           for (var i = 0; i < this.rows.length; i++) {
                  console.log(this.rows[i].from)
                  console.log(this.rows[i].to)
                  axios.post(' https://pa-staging.propnex.net/index.php/public/addDiyOpenhouse?listing-id=506&start-time='+this.rows[i].from +'&end-time='+this.rows[i].to+'&date=2020-06-20',{
                      headers: {
                      'Accept': 'application/json',
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    }
                  }).then((res)=>{
                    console.log(res);
                  })
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `axios.post` API dictates that the second parameter is for data (like form data or json, etc) and headers can be defined in the third parameter. So change you line to this syntax:

```
axios.post(url, requestData (or empty object for no data), {headers: { headerName: headerValue }})
```

Comment: its also the same sir, headers is not appearing in request headers